# Change pre-selection of a Button in a MessageBox in Java?

Tags: java, messagebox

I have the following situation:

```
MessageBox messageBox = new MessageBox(GetShell(), SWT.ICON_QUESTION | SWT.YES | SWT.NO);
      messageBox.setText("Question");
      messageBox.setMessage("Message");
      int answer = messageBox.open();
```

This outputs a MessageBox with the button "Yes" pre-selected. Is it possible to change the initial selection of "Yes" to "No" with this or can this only be done with a Dialog?

Comment: From which library is the MessageBox?

Comment: Apologies, its from org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MessageBox;

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to do that. This behaviour is given. You could, however create your own dialog by adding two Buttons and calling `forceFocus` on the button you want to:

```
Button button1 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);

Button button2 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);

button1.setText("Click me!");
button2.setText("Look at me, I have the focus now.");

//Here you set the focus to the second button
button2.forceFocus();
button1.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 30);
button2.setBounds(200, 0, 200, 30);

shell.pack();
shell.open();
//Prevent from closing
while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
  if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
    display.sleep();
  }
}
display.dispose();
```